# Can you extract a pypy3 rpm from snap?

Tags: centos, rpm, python3, snap

I have centos 7.6 at work and would like to install pypy3. For policy reasons outside my control they won't do this unless they can find an rpm to install. https://snapcraft.io/install/pypy3/centos shows how to install pypy3 using snap (which they won't use).

Is it possible to extract an rpm of pypy3 somehow from snap?

Comment: `snap` doesn't install rpms so what you are asking for isn't possible. If there were an rpm, then it could just be installed with `rpm` or `yum` and there wouldn't be any need for `snap`. The only other option is download the source code and compile it.

Comment: @NasirRiley any route to get an rpm would be great

Comment: If you can't use the `snap` route, have a look at building from source - here's a link with details on how this is done.  https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/build.html

Comment: What makes this question difficult to answer is we don't know your policy.  If they will accept an RPM from you then you can always build your own

Comment: There are good reasons why 'snap' isn't trusted.

Comment: @JeremyBoden what are they?

Comment: Clunky massive packages with static libraries + large runtime code. Lack of distro packaging means there is no guarantee of active development of snap packages. Not tested in a specific environment against other packages. Limited hosting of snaps - is it still just a Canonical thing?